# Weird problem porting application. Undefined reference errors in standard libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, porting

I've recently been trying to port a C++ application. I believe I have all of it's dependencies and such and it all compiles. But then, when it goes to link it I get a lot of weird undefined reference errors.

```
/usr/local/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.7.0: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::seekg(long, std::_Ios_Seekdir)'
/usr/local/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.7.0: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/usr/local/lib/libxml++-2.6.so.0.1: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/usr/local/lib/libxml++-2.6.so.0.1: undefined reference to `std::__default_alloc_template<true, 0>::deallocate(void*, unsigned long)'
```

What can cause this kind of errors? What do the linking errors mean? I can't really understand the complicated template error messages that gcc gives..

The linking command in it's entirety:

```
gmake[3]: Entering directory `/home/earlz/synfig-0.62.00/src/tool'
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link eg++ -I/usr/local/include/libxml++-2.6 -I/usr/local/lib/libxml++-2.6/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/local/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -DSYNFIG_NO_DEPRECATED -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DNDEBUG -O2 -W -Wall   -o synfig synfig-main.o ../synfig/libsynfig.la -L/usr/local/lib -lxml++-2.6 -lxml2 -lglibmm-2.4 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -liconv -lsigc-2.0 -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib -lsigc-2.0 -L/usr/local/lib -lintl -L/usr/local/lib -liconv  -lpthread
libtool: link: eg++ -I/usr/local/include/libxml++-2.6 -I/usr/local/lib/libxml++-2.6/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/local/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -DSYNFIG_NO_DEPRECATED -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DNDEBUG -O2 -W -Wall -o .libs/synfig synfig-main.o  -L../synfig/.libs -lsynfig -L/usr/local/lib -lxml++-2.6 -lxml2 -lm -lz -lglibmm-2.4 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lpcre -lsigc-2.0 -lintl -liconv -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
```

Also, I do not get any kind of linking errors about missing files, just stuff about weird string and filestream stuff missing

Comment: Do you link it with the `g++` command?

Comment: If you show us the command you're using to link your app it will help up give you an answer faster

Comment: Yes, it appears to be using g++ (note I use eg++ for the command name as that is how to access gcc-4.2 on my system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use g++ to link C++ applications, that add C++ standard libraries to the link phase.

Comment: Is this from standard libraries not being linked in? Thats a weird error. I don't see how this application builds on other platforms then. (compiles on Linux, but breaks with this error on OpenBSD)

Comment: The names your linker complains about let it think so.

Comment: So I hand modified the linking command to look at `/usr/lib` and to link in `-lstdc++` and it works.. freaking weird..

Comment: Earlz that is exactly what linking with a C linker would give - you are not using a C++ linker e,g, g++